# How to create associations

Tags: grpc

Say I have a GRPC order that looks like this when generated:

```
Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build do
  add_message "something.Order" do
    optional :uuid, :string, 1
    repeated :shipments, :message, 2, "something.Shipment"
    ...  
  end
end
```

So an `Order` has many `shipments`. When I create the order to send back as a response in the service... how do I create the many shipments?

Can I just do:

```
order = Order.find(request.id)
Something::Order.new(uuid: order.id, shipments: [order.shipments)
```

Or does it needs to be:

```
order = Order.find(request.id)
Something::Order.new(uuid: order.id, shipments: [order.shipments.attributes)
```

I get the latter from [these docs](https://github.com/ruby-protobuf/protobuf/wiki/Messages-&-Enums)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it looks like the google-protobuf package is used here?
(https://github.com/google/protobuf).

If that's the case, I don't think the ruby-protobuf docs are relevant here.

For using Google::Protobuf here, it looks like you should be able to add an array of Shipment objects to the 'shipments' field of an 'Order' instance.